# How to secure JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I want to secure a JpaRepository which refers to my OAuth Users to the Authorized Role `ROLE_ADMIN`. Now I want to know which Methods I need to annotate.
So as I want to secure the whole User Repository the login is not working anymore as it calls the `findByUsername(String username)` method. Is there any possibility to remove this method from the login process and restrict the parameter to the principals username?

So firstly I need to discover the standard methods inside the JpaRepository that I need to authorize. As I browsed the code I found a bunch of them but I don't think I need to explicity mention all of them.

```
List<T> findAll();
List<T> findAll(Sort sort);
List<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids);
<S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);
void flush();
<S extends T> S saveAndFlush(S entity);
void deleteInBatch(Iterable<T> entities);
void deleteAllInBatch();
T getOne(ID id);
<S extends T> List<S> findAll(Example<S> example);
<S extends T> List<S> findAll(Example<S> example, Sort sort);
Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
Iterable<T> findAll(Sort sort);
<S extends T> S save(S entity);
<S extends T> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);
Optional<T> findById(ID id);
boolean existsById(ID id);
Iterable<T> findAll();
Iterable<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids);
long count();
void deleteById(ID id);
void delete(T entity);
void deleteAll(Iterable<? extends T> entities);
void deleteAll();
<S extends T> Optional<S> findOne(Example<S> example);
<S extends T> Iterable<S> findAll(Example<S> example);
<S extends T> Iterable<S> findAll(Example<S> example, Sort sort);
<S extends T> Page<S> findAll(Example<S> example, Pageable pageable);
<S extends T> long count(Example<S> example);
<S extends T> boolean exists(Example<S> example);
```

As of now My Repository looks like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "internal:users", path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
{
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    Page<User> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    User findOne(String id);

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    User save(User u);

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    void delete(User u);

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    User insert(User u);

    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Do I need to add some more methods?

For the second question in securing the `findByUsername(String username)` method I tried to annotate with `@PreAuthorize("#username == authentication.principal.username")` but since the method is called inside the login process the login is not possible anymore.

Here is some more code:

```java
@Component
public class AppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(s);

        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("The username %s doesn't exist", s));
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        user.getRoles().forEach(role -> {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName()));
        });

        UserDetails userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);

        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  [...]

    @Autowired
    private AppUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
         DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
         authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
         authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
         return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_roles", joinColumns
            = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Role> roles;
}
```

So as of now a user who has a token is able to call the `findByUsername` method and retrieve all user information about any user. But I want that the user is only possible to retrieve its own information.

Comment: when a token is sent, it will lookup the user that the token is associated with. The token cant look up other users. So i dont really understand your question.

Comment: @Thomas That is correct. But as the search method is open to all users and I login as `test` user and use this token for calling `users/search/findByUsername?username=admin` I get all information about the admin user.

Comment: then its the url that needs securing, not the method itself

Comment: @dur You're both right, that would work but I think that it would be a more convenient way to work with controllers as Jaume's answer suggeseted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, is a bad option to publish repositories as a rest resouces. Is better have controllers and services who call repositories methods. This controllers will publish only the methods you want.

You could have two controllers: `LoginController` to process the login requests and `UserController` to process the requests abouts users. Then, you can apply security policies on each controller.

If you publish a repository, if a new Spring data version includes new methods on a JpaRepository class, this methods will be published and won't have any security policy